# Handle error in axios.get and data received in react/js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

I'm struggling to figure out how to prevent my app from crashing after fetching data from an API. Here's what I have done so far:

User searches for a word and based on that word, the program goes to a link with the searched phrase, then fetches and stores data in a const

```
var baseUrl = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${search}&apikey=****`;
```

`${search}`  = whatever the user enters in the searchbar

then baseUrl is the webite used to get all the data from API

```
  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(baseUrl)
      .then(res => {
        setChart(res.data);
        // console.log(res.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("there was an error: " + error);
      })
  }, [baseUrl]);

   useEffect(()=>{}, [chart]);
```

then the program loops thru the API and stores DATE and PRICE for each entry in const **stockPrices** and **stockDates**.

```
      const stockPrices = useMemo(() => chart && Object.values(chart['Time Series (Daily)']).map(i => i['1. open']).reverse(), [chart]); 
      const stockDates = useMemo(() => chart && Object.keys(chart['Time Series (Daily)']).map(x => x.replace(/\d{4}-/, "")).reverse(), [chart]);
```

However, sometimes if user enter a search for which there's no existing link.. the app crashes, as it's trying to loop and display data that doesn't exist.

I'm not really sure how to handle this.

In the search component, I added this little "if" statement to stop it doing anything if the search is empty ( because no such link exists ):

```
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.value !== ``) {
    setSearch(e.target.value.toUpperCase())
    }};
```

However, this only solves a small part of the problem. If the app tries to fetch data from an invalid link it simply crashes.

when the app crashes - in the console it says
"Cannot convert undefined or null to object" which is reported from the line where **const stockPrices** and **const stockDates** are sitting on.

How can I stop the app from fetching data if a link doesn't exist - how to handle this bug ?

just for context the data stored in those variables is then passed to render a chart with prices (Y-axis) and dates(X-axis) so it needs to at least have some sort of replacement..

```
if(typeof stockDates === 'undefined') {
    return ('undefined');
} else if(stockDates=== null){
    return ('null');
}
```

I tried doing this to replace bad fetch with 'null' || 'undefined' but it's still crashing.

Please help.

**IN SHORT**: App crashes if it's trying to fetch data from a link that doesn't exist ( based on input from searchbar )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what error you're facing with the search problem.

The other one's the error you get when you pass `undefined` to `Object.keys` or `Object.values` function.

I'm gonna guess the API returns some data for invalid links so chart is not undefined. In the code, you're checking to make sure `chart` is not undefined. But most likely, `chart['Time Series (Daily)']` is undefined.

I don't know enough about your requirements to suggest a fix. But you could add an additional check and make it so...

```
const stockPrices = useMemo(() => chart && chart['Time Series (Daily)'] && Object.values(chart['Time Series (Daily)']).map(i => i['1. open']).reverse(), [chart]); 
const stockDates = useMemo(() => chart && chart['Time Series (Daily)'] && Object.keys(chart['Time Series (Daily)']).map(x => x.replace(/\d{4}-/, "")).reverse(), [chart]);
```

But I think it'd be better to fix the fetch code.

```
axios.get(baseUrl)
.then(res => {
    if (res.data?.['Time Series (Daily)']) {
        setChart(res.data);
    }
    else {
        setChart(undefined);
        //maybe set some error states so you can display the appropriate message?
    }
})
```

Comment: in short it's a stock market app... let's say a user tries to look up apple stock which has a symbol of "AAPL" and accidentally types in APPLE - then the app will crash because he will make the app fetch this link: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=APPLE&apikey=K6Z6JO9JU1FFTLP3   and it's a bad link... https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=AAPL&apikey=K6Z6JO9JU1FFTLP3 <--- this is the right one

Comment: i'll check out your suggestion and see if it helps.. thank you

Comment: ooh, I see what you're saying - that's interesting..

Comment: Is that a private API key?...

Comment: @MattSzumilo have your solve it?

Comment: if u use 'demo' for API it's a free version.. but I do have a free api key
anyways @thurasw your version of const stockPrices and const stockDates helped stop the app from crashing ! And I can go back, and re-type a stock name and if it's a proper symbol, it fetches the proper data !!! Would you mind explaining the logic for doing it this way?

Comment: hey @VMT yeah thurasw's answer was just what I needed ! I think his answer checks if there's  data in chart, and in chart - > time series daily and only then it stores data... this stopped the app from crashing

Comment: once again, thank you THURASW !!! I was on the edge of giving up on this project - I realy appreciate it. ... and thank you to everyone else who pitched in to help resolve this issue <3

Comment: Your `chart` variable is the data returned by your API. Try and open the two links you provided. When the symbol is valid, the link returns the full data with `Time Series (Daily)`. When the symbol is invalid, the link still returns data, but without the property. So now, your chart variable doesn't have the `Time Series (Daily)` property inside. You weren't really checking to see if the data was present or not.